# how to bind a gridview to a table has a foreign key

Tags: c#, datagridview, ef-code-first

i have table that has 3 foregin key now i want show that in a gridview, the class of table:

```
[Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("FldKeyId")]
    public int MyKeyId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Machine Machine { get; set; }  
    [Required]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Shift Shift { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column ("FldStartTime")]
    public DateTime MyStartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Column ("FldEndTime")]
    public DateTime MyEndTime { get; set; }
    [Column("FldModificationDate")]
    [Required]
    public DateTime ModificationDate { get; set; }
```

and that is the code for bind to grid view

```
void RefreshBreakGrid()
    {
        dgvcolDate.DataPropertyName = "ModificationDate";
        dgvcolstarttime.DataPropertyName = "MyStartTime";
        dgvcolendtime.DataPropertyName = "MyEndTime";

        dgvcolemployee.DataSource = Employee.GetAllEmployee();
        dgvcolemployee.DisplayMember = "MyName";
        dgvcolemployee.ValueMember = "MyKeyId";
        dgvcolemployee.DataPropertyName = "Employee";


        dgvcolmachine.DataSource = Machine.GetAllMachine();
        dgvcolmachine.DisplayMember = "MyName";
        dgvcolmachine.ValueMember = "MyKeyId";
        dgvcolmachine.DataPropertyName = "Machine";

        dgvcolshift.DataSource = Shift.GetAllShift();
        dgvcolshift.DisplayMember = "MyName";
        dgvcolshift.ValueMember = "MyKeyId";
        dgvcolshift.DataPropertyName = "Shift";

        _Breaks=Break.GetAllBreak();
        dgvBreak.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        dgvBreak.DataSource = _Breaks;
    }
```

for example methode of getall company:

```
public static List<Break> GetAllBreak()
{
    return new ContexManager().Breaks.Where(c => c.MyKeyId != 0).Include(c => c.Machine).Include(c => c.Employee).Include(c => c.Shift).ToList();
}
```

and when i run this code gridview shown `classLibrary.classes.shift` fro shift field what i have to do show the currect value in gridview.
i have use winforms and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it solved with override `toString()` methode of each class